# What is the cheapest computer (mobo/CPU) that can run windows 11

Tags: processor

The purpose is to run some bitcoin wallet and will rarely be opened or anything.

I want to run electrum, exodus, that's it. Maybe anti malewarebytes.

I got some cheap computer but my partner want something that can run windows 11. Maybe with TPM I guess.

I am thinking of some mobo and CPU combination. Speed is not important as long as it's not too slow.

What would be the one I should buy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saying, maybe if it's some kinda server you are better off with a second hand PC and install Linux, since that is generally more stable. The rest of the answer works both for Windows 11 and Linux.

If you can still get it around €50, the AMD Athlon 3000G is an excellent CPU for your use case. You don't need a GPU to POST or boot, it's cheap and can run basic server stuff (like a bitcoin wallet that does not mine too, or a web server like Apache for your bitcoin wallet interface). For the motherboard, I have the MSI B450M -A pro MAX. It has most features you would want on a server, except ECC support, and should work perfectly with the Athlon 3000G (I have not tested this though, but according to the MSI website it does)

Comment: any site that  compare prices?

Comment: In the netherlands and belgium, you can use Tweakers.net or Hardware.info. For other countries, I don't know

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/578395/why-doesnt-my-athlon-3000g-apply-to-windows-11-via it's a gamble. Most athlon 3000G won't

Comment: Interesting, I have not seen that one yet... Maybe the R3 3200G is a safer buy then